# iPhone web form prev/next skips radio buttons - how to fix?

Tags: html, ios, tabindex

I have a website with an html form (PHP server side). When I tab through the fields using the prev/next button on the iPhone the "radio group" gets skipped. However, text fields, lists and buttons get selected. Is it possible to enable a radio group to be selected using prev/next buttons?

Or should I change this from a "radio group" to something like a list menu?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed as not a real question, since it is a real question.

Comment: I think this is a real question. Maybe revising the title will help. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have radio buttons selected with the previous and next buttons.  Instead, you should detect the iOS user agent and replace the radio buttons with a custom select control.  (Or just get rid of the radio buttons entirely.)

More info and code samples can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006512-SW1